# Java Hibernate validation return invalid fields

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I am working with Validation annotations from Java Hibernate in my projects. I want to validate the data that I receive and return an array of invalid fields. Is that possible?

Let's say I have a Java class named `Car`:

```
public class Car {

    @NotNull
    private String manufacturer;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 14)
    @CheckCase(CaseMode.UPPER)
    private String licensePlate;

    @Min(2)
    private int seatCount;

    public Car ( String manufacturer, String licencePlate, int seatCount ) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.licensePlate = licencePlate;
        this.seatCount = seatCount;
    }

    //getters and setters ...
}
```

Let's say I create a new Car:

```
Car c = new Car("AUDI", NULL, 1);
```

This should not be possible because the license plate should be filled in and the number of seats should be greater than or equal to 2. So I want to return an array of two elements saying that license plate and number of seats are invalid (with extra message if possible).

Comment: Are you unable to add code to your Car initialization function, to test for and deal with those conditions?

Comment: Maybe question is not clear. I want to validate the car that I create and return an array of the fields which are not valid

Answer (score 1):

As [ElmerCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3799712/elmercat) points out, your constructor should be defined as:

```
public Car (
  @NotNull String manufacturer,
  @NotNull @Size(min = 2, max = 14) @CheckCase(CaseMode.UPPER) String licensePlate,
  @Min(2) int seatCount) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
    this.seatCount = seatCount;
}
```